# why won't some custom keyboard shortcuts work?

Tags: command-line, gnome, bash, keyboard, shortcut-keys

**GNOME Shell 3.26.2 | Ubuntu 17.10 | Bash 4.4.12**

I have tried setting `xclip -o >> ~/directory/filename.txt` as a custom keyboard shortcut to no avail. I have tried setting it to multiple key configurations ([<kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>return</kbd>] , [<kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> ] , [<kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>spacebar</kbd>] etc.. ) none work. I have double checked the command in terminal, and I know I haven't mistyped. why would setting this command as a custom keyboard shortcut be an issue?

This is not the first time this has happened either. Do certain commands require a system restart? are there certain key combinations that don't work? ( I could not set [<kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>] to open terminal, for instance, but [<kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>] did. )

Comment: Very interested to know why that worked. man bash said of -c, "If  the -c option is present, then commands are
                 read from the first  non-option  argument  com‐
                 mand_string.   If there are arguments after the
                 command_string, the first argument is  assigned
                 to  $0 and any remaining arguments are assigned
                 to the positional parameters.   The  assignment
                 to $0 sets the name of the shell, which is used
                 in warning and error messages." the bash man page isn't very n00b friendly.

Comment: What does it mean to wrap a command in a shell? I would like to learn a lot more on the subject but don't really know where to start. Should I do a web search on shell environments? I am very much still learning. Thanks for the help

Comment: I was having the same issue, and can verify that wrapping it in `bash -c "my-command"` worked for me.  @dsstorefile1 - you might consider adding that comment as a proper answer to this question-- I'd certainly upvote it.  Thanks!