# Custom keyboard shortcut does not work for launching some packages in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: gnome, keyboard, python, shortcut-keys, jupyter

In Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, I cannot get the custom keyboard shortcuts to work for certain commands (mostly for launching Python IDEs). Specifically, custom keyboard shortcuts for neither `jupyter notebook` nor `spyder` work.

For example, I want to set "Ctrl + J" as the custom keyboard shortcut to launch jupyter notebook (instead of having to open a terminal and type `jupyter notebook` in the terminal).

When I go to Settings -> Devices -> Keyboard, and create a custom shortcut where "Ctrl + J" is the shortcut for the command `jupyter notebook`, it does not work. However, if I set the same shortcut (Ctrl+J) for other commands (like `firefox`, for example), then it works. This is also the case for when I try to set a shortcut for launching `spyder`.

tl;dr - I am able to set custom keyboard shortcuts for any command, but not for launching `jupyter notebook` or `spyder`.

I tried to replace the custom keyboard shortcut command with the `bash -c "command name"` option as suggested [in this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1011426/why-wont-some-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-work), but that also does not work: [see screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxMZw.png).

Also - I do not have this problem on my laptop with the identical operating system, but this is an issue on my desktop for some reason.

Any help would be appreciated, Thank you!